# Instant messages in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, instant-messaging

I need your help to solve next issue: I am developing MVC application and want to send instant messages between users. This message will ne standard - it's like notification. I am thinking about two optins:

- use XMPP protocot, but I don't need the huge amount of options it could provide, I need just basic functionality I've discribed;
- have some static array in MVC application with users invitations were send to and ajax function which will call controller action, check if user is in static list. If yes - make message visible on the page. And plus do page autoupdate. But I am not sure about this becouse array will be called very often.

What do you think, guys? Do you have any ideas? I will be very thankfull for any help!

Answer (score 4):

You may take a look at [SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Also checkout Jabbr which is built on SignalR:

https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR

This is a chat application written by the author of SignalR David Fowler.

Answer (score 0):

You can set jquery timer to update messages with ajax. And when user writes message , it can be saved in Cache or in database if you want to save it permanently.